# Are tuna pouches still good after being in fridge?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, tuna

I have unopened pouches of tuna in the fridge with expiration date of 9/1/23.

My question is, are they still good if I take them out of fridge and store at room temperature? We are moving and I have several pouches that I would like to take with, me as long as they are still good!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the product?  Are these packages meant to be shelf stable, or are they meant to be refrigerated?

Comment: its Star Kist chunk lite tuna in water, flavor fresh pouch

Answer (score 3):

Your product is shelf-stable.  The expiration is a "best-by" date, meaning the quality degrades, but it remains safe.  Refrigeration has no relevancy, unless you opened the package.